# Pb with circular imports

Tags: python

I have this four classes which decribe a World, with Cat and Mouse and only a method in Animal to search for a specific Animal (a Cat or a Mouse).

All the code in a single file works (it prints : "I'm a Mouse") but if I split one class per file, I get this error message :

```
if isinstance(ani,getattr(sys.modules[__name__],className)):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Mouse'
```

**Class Animal**

```
import sys

class Animal(object):

def searchAnimal(self,animals,className):
    theAnimal = None              
    for ani in animals:
        if isinstance(ani,getattr(sys.modules[__name__],className)): 
            theAnimal = ani    
    return theAnimal
```

**Class Mouse**

```
from Animal import * 

class Mouse(Animal):

    def __str__(self):
        return "I'm a mouse"
```

**Class Cat**

```
from Animal import *

class Cat(Animal):

    def __str__(self):
        return "I'm a cat"
```

**Class World**

```
from Cat import *
from Mouse import *

class World(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.animals = []  
        for i in range(0,2):   # 2 Cats
            self.animals.append(Cat())
        for i in range(0,5):  # and 5 Mice
            self.animals.append(Mouse())            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    aWorld = World()
    theCat = aWorld.animals[0]
    ani = theCat.searchAnimal(aWorld.animals,"Mouse")
    print(ani)
```

How can I solve this pb? It's probably due to circular import.

Thanks,

Philippe

Comment: It seems that you are trying to use a convoluted way of solving this problem. could you explain a little more what you are trying to achieve/design ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no circular import happening here.

the issue is that `sys.modules[__name__]` will return the module from which the function is being called. in your case, the module will be `module animal`. Which does not have the class definition for `Mouse`

when you have all the classes defined in the same module, `sys.modules[__name__]` will return the same module and it will work.

A slightly better way is to store the type of the animal in the class (during initialization)

**animal.py**

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = None

    def searchAnimal(self,animals,aniType):
        theAnimal = None
        for ani in animals:
            if ani.type == aniType:
                theAnimal = ani
        return theAnimal
```

**cat.py**

```
from animal import *

class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = 'cat'
    def __str__(self):
        return "I'm a cat"
```

**mouse.py**

```
from animal import *

class Mouse(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = 'mouse'
    def __str__(self):
        return "I'm a mouse"
```

**world.py**

```
from cat import *
from mouse import *

class World(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.animals = []
        for i in range(0,2):   # 2 Cats
            self.animals.append(Cat())
        for i in range(0,5):  # and 5 Mice
            self.animals.append(Mouse())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    aWorld = World()
    theCat = aWorld.animals[0]
    ani = theCat.searchAnimal(aWorld.animals,"mouse")
    print(ani)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. I'm sorry but I can't vote up because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: In the first version of my program, I use : if isinstance(ani,eval(className)): instead of if isinstance(ani,getattr(sys.modules[__name__],className)): but it doesn't work too. Is it the same kind of problem that the one you describe?

Comment: Yes, when you do `eval(expr)` python tries to evaluate the expression in the current [namespace](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces). Because 'Mouse' does not exist in that namespace, it will throw a NameError.